# Xamarin Forms PushAsync not animating

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, animation, mobile

After the login page, I PushAsync a MainPage having one Listview and a CollectionView that are mocked up for now. What I see is the loss of fade animation due (probably) to the heaviness of the page, in fact there's a little time lag in the transition. How is it possible even if I'm not doing heavy operations?
I tested with an empty page having just two colored boxes and the fade animation transition works well, but in this case not.
I tried using Binding and list initialization through code, but the result is the same.

Below the code:
MainPage.cs

```
using BrScanner.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace BrScanner
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ObservableCollection<string> OrdersVertical { get; } 
        public ObservableCollection<ArticleForOrdineOTI> Orders { get;}
        public MainPage()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            OrdersVertical = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "Ordine 1", "Ordine 2", "Ordine 3", "Ordine 1", "Ordine 2", "Ordine 3", "Ordine 1", "Ordine 2", "Ordine 3" };
            Orders = new ObservableCollection<ArticleForOrdineOTI>(){
                new ArticleForOrdineOTI()
                {
                    Oarti = 22,
                    Carti = "Carti",
                    Tarti = "Descrizione Ordine OTI"
                },
                new ArticleForOrdineOTI()
                {
                    Oarti = 45,
                    Carti = "Carti",
                    Tarti = "Descrizione Ordine OTI"
                },
                new ArticleForOrdineOTI()
                {
                    Oarti = 76,
                    Carti = "Carti",
                    Tarti = "Descrizione Ordine OTI"
                }
            };

            ordersList.ItemsSource = OrdersVertical;
            horizOrders.ItemsSource = Orders;
            //BindingContext = this;
        }

        

        private async void New_OrderOTI_Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var orderPage = new OrderOTIPage();
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new test(), true);
        }
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:flex="clr-namespace:Flex.Controls;assembly=Flex"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="BrScanner.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <AbsoluteLayout>
            <Grid x:Name="mainGrid" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <CollectionView 
                x:Name="horizOrders" 
                HeightRequest="250" 
                MinimumHeightRequest="250"
                Grid.Row="0"
                
                ItemsLayout="HorizontalList"
                    >
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Frame 
                                HasShadow="True" 
                                Margin="5" 
                                Padding="20" 
                                CornerRadius="5"
                                    >
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Tarti}" FontSize="Medium"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Oarti}"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Carti}"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Carti}"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Carti}"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Carti}"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Carti}"/>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </Frame>
                            </StackLayout>


                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
                <ListView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ordersList" >
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout>
                                    <Label Text="Ordine nr. 26"/>
                                    <Label Text="by Ivan Ardillo"/>
                                    <Label Text="consegnato alle 12:34"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
                
            </Grid>
            <flex:FlexButton
                Clicked="New_OrderOTI_Button_Clicked"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".9, .99, 80, 80"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                WidthRequest="76"
                HeightRequest="76"
                CornerRadius="38"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Icon="brcode_icon_128px.png"
                ForegroundColor="#ffffff"
                HighlightForegroundColor="#49516F"
                BackgroundColor="#607D8B"
                HighlightBackgroundColor="#8EA4D2"/>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you think the lag is caused by heavy UI, you can try to load data in `OnAppearing` method instead of the construction method.

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    OrdersVertical = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "Ordine 1", "Ordine 2", "Ordine 3", "Ordine 1", "Ordine 2", "Ordine 3", "Ordine 1", "Ordine 2", "Ordine 3" };
    Orders = new ObservableCollection<ArticleForOrdineOTI>(){
        new ArticleForOrdineOTI()
        {
            Oarti = 22,
            Carti = "Carti",
            Tarti = "Descrizione Ordine OTI"
        },
        new ArticleForOrdineOTI()
        {
            Oarti = 45,
            Carti = "Carti",
            Tarti = "Descrizione Ordine OTI"
        },
        new ArticleForOrdineOTI()
        {
            Oarti = 76,
            Carti = "Carti",
            Tarti = "Descrizione Ordine OTI"
        }
    };

    ordersList.ItemsSource = OrdersVertical;
    horizOrders.ItemsSource = Orders;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Anyway, I tried like you said but no luck.
I was wondering if there's some guidelines for improving performances on animations and stuff like that.

Comment: No, the push animation is controlled by system api and you can't improve it. If you can share us a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I will look into it.